# Not being able to add Tapku library into XCode 4.2 project

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, tapku

I tried following [this](https://github.com/devinross/tapkulibrary/wiki/Adding-Tapku-to-Your-Project-in-XCode-4) tutorial from the author's github repository, but unsuccessfully. When I try to build the project I get 6 errors.

5 of them are

> Use of undeclared identifier '_accessibleElements'

and 1 of them is

> Receiver type 'TKCalendarMonthTiles' for instance message does not
>   declare a method with selector 'rectForCellAtIndex'

All errors are reported inside TKCalendarMonthView.m file

Comment: (1) Does the class `TKCalendarMonthView` declare an ivar `_accessibleElements` (2) Does the class `TKCalendarMonthTiles` declare a method `rectForCellAtIndex:`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears the class `TKCalendarMonthTiles` declares a property:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *accessibleElements;
```

which is not synthesized in the class implementation.  Since no `_accessibleElements` ivar is declared, then you get the undeclared identifier error that you mention.

For this error, you can either build on Xcode 4.4 to autosynthesize declared properties, or add:

```
@synthesize accessibleElements = _accessibleElements
```

in the `TKCalendarMonthTiles` implementation

Now, for your second error.  This is also due to building on Xcode 4.2 instead of 4.4.  As of 4.4 (or maybe 4.3, I can't recall) you do not need to declare private methods in a class extension.  But since you are building with Xcode 4.2, you will need to add the method declaration to a class extension on `TKCalendarMonthTiles`

```
@interface TKCalendarMonthTiles ()
- (CGRect)rectForCellAtIndex:(int)index;
@end
```

Comment: Alan, you rock :D. Thanks alot. This did the trick. Vote up and accepting this.

Answer (score 1):

I also had this same problem. I worked on it forever, gave up. Upgraded to xCode 4.5 and voila. It worked. Wish I would have seen this forum back then. Thanks peeps